# PhD offer - Making decisions on right PhD

Tags: phd, application, career-path, united-kingdom, physics

I hope everyone is well. I would like some advice about accepting PhD offers/waiting for the 'perfect' phd.

I don't want to over-explain my situation, but I think the background is important, as I am struggling with where I stand as a candidate (my chances of getting a phd, so I want to explain a little)..

Here is my situation in terms of grades/experience:

- I had a hard time at uni with mental health and working too much to support myself financially in 2nd-3rd year causing me to fail an entire semester (i pushed through which give me confidence that I am capable - I was not given this opportunity to redo the year and my grades are on my transcript (sometimes they take them off if you have mitigating circumstances, which I never claimed for during this time.)
- I did a summer project which led to publication in field of astrochemistry- best summer ever - decided I love physics and started thinking about phd.
- Final year (Integrated MPhys) I found my feet and decided I love research and got a First class that year (80%+ in my project)
- I graduated with an overall 2:1 MPhys (just) and have not-so-great-grades on my transcipt from the 2nd and 3rd year (a few fails in more complex topics such as theoretical and cosmology)
- I am interested in high energy cosmology/astrophysics, but I have a love for the environment too and obviously climate change is super relevant and important.

Because of my grades/experience, I never thought I would be good enough to do a PhD, but in my final year I loved it so much and managed to get the grades to be able to pursue one if I wanted to.

------------ Fast forward 6 months  ------------

Finally decided research is definitely what I want to do. I missed all the deadlines (my new job took over and I not 100% sure what field I want to go into). I applied late to a PhD (funding was late so timing was perfect) related to atmospheric physics in the department of environmental science : when I saw it it seemed to tick most of my boxes:

- location
- supervisor
- physics/climate science which I love
- multidisciplinary research group (lots of exposure) and really lovely team (important to me as I am a people person)

I got accepted, which to me was a surprise. I got through on the basis of a face-to-face interview and a CV. Was this a lucky coincidence or am I actually a good candidate?

Here's the but: I love astronomy, radio astronomy, high energy particle physics and cosmology and have experience in these fields - they are challenging (which scares me) but also is exciting. However, **very** competitive. I am afraid my grades are not good enough for these topics and my chances of getting a phd within this field, at a good institution are slim. Also, it is possible I am not 'good' at these subjects due to failed past grades. This being said, my research in these topics has always been very high standard in labs and projects. Do grades really matter? This is super difficult for me to decide what avenue of research to go down, as I have so many interests, and a PhD is a huge commitment - I want to make sure I am the right fit.

---- Summary -----

I have a great offer from a fantastic uni in a topic i love (climate/environmental science), but its not physics and I am worried I wont enjoy it or regret my choice.

Should I accept the offer because I was lucky enough to bag one, in a topic I do love, but giving up another love of mine: astronomy and risk not getting a PhD at all.

I also feel super guilty that I have un-officially had an offer for some time and another candidate could have my position so there is some time sensitivity on this.

I am also worried about wasting another year. I have taken this academic year off to work in order to save, pay off debts and get myself in a better financial situation to avoid what happened previously. This PhD will be starting in September 2020, however, if I decline, I will have to wait another year before I can apply again - I really dont like my job (not relevant to my future and I am not learning anything that will improve my CV) and getting a new one I like, or doing research internships is unlikely at the moment due to lockdown.

Apologies for the long winded and detailed post but I hope someone can relate and offer some advice on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question will likely be closed as it's not really applicable to others, but I hope I can offer some insight. I'm a finishing PhD student in cosmology in the UK so think my perspective is relevant.

Firstly, I want to address what sounds to me like a classic case of imposter syndrome. You say

> I got through on the basis of a face-to-face interview and a CV. Was
>   this a lucky coincidence or am I actually a good candidate?

There are no lucky coincidences when it comes to hiring PhD students. You've been chosen due to your excellent track record in research (having a publication as an undergraduate is a big achievement and something you should be very proud of) and your clear passion for the subject. The admissions committee are likely all senior lecturers or professors who've probably supervised 30+ students between them. They know a good candidate when they spot one. Your offer was not a fluke.

> Here's the but: I love astronomy, radio astronomy, high energy
>   particle physics and cosmology and have experience in these fields -
>   they are challenging (which scares me) but also is exciting. However,
>   very competitive. I am afraid my grades are not good enough for these
>   topics and my chances of getting a phd within this field, at a good
>   institution are slim.

Every field of research is challenging, and unfortunately, I don't think atmospheric physics/climate science is any less competitive than those you list here. That being said, competitiveness is not a good metric to decide what to study. You will have a miserable time doing a PhD on a subject you're not 100% committed to and interested in. Only you can tell whether this applies to atmospheric physics or cosmology for you.

> Do grades really matter?

Yes and no. Your grades are clearly good enough to make you a competitive PhD applicant, since you have an offer in hand. However, really poor grades in every cosmology/astrophysics/astronomy module you've taken might be a concern for an admissions committee. You can mitigate such a scenario with a good track record in research, which you seem to have. If you were to apply to a cosmology PhD I think you'd have a good chance of success -- but I think this would be much better judged by someone who knows you and your work well, such as your personal tutor or MPhys project supervisor. I am sure they would welcome an email from you asking for their advice.

You also seem to feel the time pressure to accept, to not waste another year. Ignore the time pressure. This decision should not be rushed. Even if you're really not enjoying your job, it's not the end of the world if you do decide to apply again next year rather than taking the offer you have in hand. Supervisors would generally rather take a student who has some life experience, perspective and real motivation to complete a PhD, rather than someone fresh out of undergrad who's applying just because they don't know what to do next. You will not be reducing your chances of getting another offer by taking this route.

Overall, the decision is yours, and above all else must be based on which topic you would really prefer to study. You weren't "lucky" to bag an offer (well, naturally a small amount of luck and good timing comes into it), you were offered a PhD on the merit of your previous work and research experience. There's no reason to believe you wouldn't be able to get another offer next year.

Comment: Off-topic, but I'm happy to talk informally about what doing a PhD in cosmology is like. You can find my email address via my stackexchange profile.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you so much for taking the time to write this response - it is really nice to hear this feedback from the view of someone with experience. I will take on everything you have said, and will not rush this decision. Thank you again for the clarity and your thoughts on this.